Azure Pipelines and .NET versions
This is sending me absolutely mad and I'm not sure if it's the diagnostics leading me astray, or I'm actually using the wrong versions
I have a build pipeline in azure, it builds a .NET Core minimal API. This thing has one endpoint. It works wonderfully well - when I merge to Main, a pipeline begins - it has many steps - but for the interests of this question lets assume it has two. These two:
Step 1: Install the .NET Core SDK
Step 2: Build a project
So, given:
steps:
 - task: UseDotNet@2
   displayName: 'Install SDK'
   inputs:
       version: 8.x

.... which produces
Successfully installed .NET Core sdk version 8.0.401.
Creating global tool path and pre-pending to PATH.
Finishing: Install .NET Core SDK

... in a subsequent step where I invoke:
inputs: 
   command: 'build'

... why does the diagnostic output show

Description : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version : 2.244.1
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================

##[warning]Resource file has already set to: /home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.244.1/node_modules/azure-pipelines-tasks-packaging-common/module.json

Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.

1.) how could it possibly build on 2.2/3 and then warn me not to use those things?
2.) why does it not use what I asked on step 1?
Has it actually not used .NET 8 here? Is the info message present for all? Am I missing something?
Please save me from the insanity...
UPDATE:
TLDR - the warning is information and does not relate to your choices (not great, imo) - secondly, the version showing in diagnostics is the version of the Dotnet Task, which just so happens to be the same version as the end of life SDKs.... so it's just a diagnostic confusion issue.

That's just information that tells that those versions are EOL. Not because they are used by your build-command.
The build would have failed if the machine running the pipeline only hade .NET Core 2.2/3

Yep, it's just a warning displayed when using the Microsoft-hosted agents. You can double-check the .NET version currently being used in the pipeline by adding a script task with the dotnet --version command after the UseDotNet@2 task.

Use also dotnet --list-sdks before and/or after installing the SDK to see which SDKs are available.

The actual warning message (not the info message) relates to a bug:
[https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/20408]
[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/DotNetCoreCLI2-Task-Version-22441-la/10731505]


Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents.

This is the info message built into the dotnet task version 2 in Azure DevOps. And it was added to dotnet task since 2020. All users who use dotnet task version 2 will see this info message.
Refer to this task commit related to the change: [DotnetCoreCLIV2]removing versions deprecation warning and making it info message
This info message is intended to remind projects using .net 2.2 and 3.0 that they need to use Use dotnet core task to install the required old SDK. It is not used to display the .net SDK version used by the current Pipeline.
It has no effect on your current build and can completely ignore this info log.

why does it not use what I asked on step 1?

Based on your Pipeline definition, the dotnet build should have used the dotnet version you set.
You can add an additional script task before the dotnet build task to run the command: dotnet --version to confirm the dotnet version.
For example:
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 8.x'
  inputs:
    version: 8.x

- script: 'dotnet --version'
  displayName: 'Check dotnet version'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

When you check the script task, it will show the current dotnet version used in the Pipeline.
For example:

Currently, this info message does not support hiding in dotnet task version 2.
If you don't want to see info messages in the log, you can consider the following methods:

Change to use old version of dotnet task: DotNetCoreCLI@1 - .NET Core v1 task

Change to use script task(powershell/bash/cmd) to directly run dotnet command in Azure Pipelines.



Thanks Kevin. It's that version number in the output diagnostics showing '2.237.1' which really threw me here. To me, that looked like the .NET runtime or SDK telling me its version number, which as you've made clear, it is not.
I appreciate the comprehensive answer!

@SpaceBison This is the pipeline task version: 2.237.1.  Not the .net sdk version. From your YAML sample, I can confirm that the dotnet build task will use the correct .net 8 sdk.

Yeah, I get that - but combine with the info message which isn't relevant and it creates a confusing diagnostics scenario.

Oh. I can get your point now(taskversion 2.2xx and info message: .net2.2). It's a bit confusing indeed. But these info messages can be ignored. They will not affect your build.  You can continue to complete the development in Pipeline. Happy coding!
